# ngSemantic select doesn't bind to object

Tags: angular, forms, html-select, semantic-ui

i'm using Angular2 and `ngSemantic` library. I created a form and here is my code:

Template file:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>My first form</h1>
    <form class="ui form" [formGroup]="myForm">
        <sm-loader [complete]="!submitted" class="inverted" text="Loading..."></sm-loader>

        <div class="field">
            <sm-select [(model)]="firstSelect" [control]="myForm.controls.category" placeholder="Search..." class="fluid search">
                <option *ngFor="let item of itemslist" [value]="item">{{item.name}}</option>
            </sm-select>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <sm-select placeholder="Search..." class="fluid search">
                <option *ngFor="let i of firstSelect?.items">{{i}}</option>
            </sm-select>
        </div>

        <sm-button (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!myForm.valid" class="primary">Login</sm-button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Component file:

```
itemslist: any = [
    { name: 'first', items: ['one', 'two', 'three']},
    { name: 'second', items: ['one', 'two', 'three']},
    { name: 'third', items: ['one', 'two', 'three']}
];

constructor(private dataService: DataService, fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
        'category': [],
        'subcategory': [],
        'name': [],
        'email': []
    });
}
```

The loop in the second select doesn't work because `firstSelect` results to be a string instead of `Object`. Maybe this happens because `select`/`option` deal with `string` or `number` only.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`{{...}}` does string interpolation. Don't use it if you want to pass an object instance.

For object binding use instead

```
[value]="item"
```

Comment: Yes, i know. I edited my question, it was a typo. Sorry and thank you for your reply. Anyway it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know `sm-select` but for the normal select you need to use `[ngValue]="..."` when binding objects instead of strings on the `<options>` element.

Comment: I know. If use `select` and `ngValue` on `option` it works :(